# How to read index from hdfs in Lucene

Tags: java, hadoop, solr, lucene

Hi I am using Lucene to search data in hive udf. So my index directory will be in hdfs. How can I use Lucene to read hdfs directory for index. below is few code snippet.

```
IndexReader indexReader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(new File(url)));
IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
```

In url I am passing hdfs location of index as below
**hdfs://localhost:9000/home/input_all/index/spatial_search_index**

Please tell me how can I do this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucene does not support HDFS out of the box.

You should be using [HdfsDirectory](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_6_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/store/hdfs/HdfsDirectory.html) or something like that, standard `DirectoryReader` simply won't work.

Comment: Then is there a way by which I can place index at some system, and hive udf (which runs in mapreduce) can access this index

Comment: And why can't you use `HdfsDirectory` I mentioned?

Comment: @agarwal_achhnera I have asked on how to implement this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36324870/example-reading-lucene-index-from-hdfs can any of you help me out. Any help is appreciated